# how do I install dlib version 19.22 for facial recognition with a webcam?

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to make a facial recognition program that uses my webcam however I am trying to install dlib version 19.22 and it keeps saying that CMake needs to be installed even though I already have.

[terminal showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGGlP.png)

I already tried to install cmake different ways using homebrew and even tried a virtual environment but neither option worked. However just saying **pip install dlib** works but **pip install dlib==19.22** doesn't